# Como exportar a txt desde tableexport en php?

Tags: php, html, txt

Buenas quisiera saber como exportar a txt una tabla respetando las filas y columnas, ya que logro exportar pero el archivo queda desordenado.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?¿Puedes poner un [mcve]?

Comment: Coloca tu codigo